# Why does Eclipse provide me with less settings when I import a project?

Tags: c++, eclipse

Creating a C++-project in Eclipse provides you with the "Tool Settings" in the Project->Properties under C/C++ Build->Settings.

Importing existing source files into a new project for some reason, OMIT those exact "Tool Settings".

I need those settings however. So why is eclipse doing this, and how can I prevent it from doing it?

Comment: Its this import as makefile project? If so, the tool settings are expected to be controlled by the makefile.

Comment: You may find it easier to create a new empty project in (or around) the existing source tree or create a new empty project and copy into the new project (or check out the existing source from version control into the new empty project.)